# Crypto Hmac node.js equivalent for ruby for the following function

Tags: node.js, ruby, openssl, hmac, cryptojs

```
function hmac(key, string, encoding) {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(string, 'utf8').digest(encoding);
}
function hash(string, encoding) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(string, 'utf8').digest(encoding);
}
```

For the above function hmac encoding is optional, or else it have value 'hex'
I checked the OpenSsl library in ruby and found similar functions but not getting the same outputs when running in ruby.

Following link is used as reference to some extend but not exactly.Anyone have came across similar use case.Please let me know

Answer (score 5):

This is a very old question but I was just trying to do the same thing and figured posting an answer for posterity wouldn't hurt.

The Ruby equivalents I came up with are significantly more verbose because I am not aware of a way to pass the encoding as an argument to any of the methods.

**Note:** `base64` and `hex` encodings are equivalent between JS and Ruby. It looks like there could be a difference in the output of Node's `latin1` encoding depending on how Ruby is configured, but I believe the raw bytes are equivalent.

```ruby
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

def hmac(key, string, encoding = 'hex')
  hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.new(key, 'sha256')
  hmac << string
  case encoding
    when 'base64'
      Base64.encode64(hmac.digest)
    when 'hex'
      hmac.hexdigest
    else
      hmac.digest
  end
end

def hash(string, encoding = 'hex')
  sha256 = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
  sha256 << string
  case encoding
    when 'base64'
      Base64.encode64(sha256.digest)
    when 'hex'
      sha256.hexdigest
    else
      sha256.digest
  end
end

key = "NjNsSSpyaE83NyZGaGdpYXhLQmFjVUJhZ3UyMENqZWY="
string = "this is a test"
encoding = "hex";
puts hmac(key, string, encoding) # => adb2946c2815047327d51459b401836cebb1a31644604303b4886b028bb98e69
puts hash(string, encoding) # => 2e99758548972a8e8822ad47fa1017ff72f06f3ff6a016851f45c398732bc50c
```

And to test, you can simply run the equivalent in node

```js
var key = "NjNsSSpyaE83NyZGaGdpYXhLQmFjVUJhZ3UyMENqZWY="
var string = "this is a test"
var encoding = "hex";
console.log(hmac(key, string, encoding)) // => adb2946c2815047327d51459b401836cebb1a31644604303b4886b028bb98e69
console.log(hash(string, encoding)) // => 2e99758548972a8e8822ad47fa1017ff72f06f3ff6a016851f45c398732bc50c
```